# how do I update the value of each row without primary key?

Tags: php, sql-update, odbc

I want to update the value in a certain row. But it seems impossible since this table (from database) doesn't have the primary key. It only have two foreign key in its column. What should I do ? please, any help ?

here is my code :

```
<table align= "center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<?php

        $strgettable="select tblUsrGrp.UsrGrpNama, tblmenu.MenuNama, tblmenuakses.MenuAkses
                     FROM tblUsrGrp
                     inner join tblMenuAkses 
                     on tblUsrGrp.UsrGrpID = tblMenuAkses.usrgrpid
                     inner join tblMenu 
                     on tblMenu.menuid = tblMenuAkses.menuid";
        $varRecCount=0;
        $rs=odbc_exec($dbconnVOT, $strgettable);
        if($rs)
        {

            echo '<tr><td style=width:10%;>';
            echo '<center><b> No. </b></center>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td style=width:30%;>';
            echo '<center><b> User Group </b></center>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td style=width:20%;>';
            echo '<center><b> Menu Name </b></center>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td style=width:20%;>';
            echo '<center><b> Menu Akses </b></center>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td style=width:20%;>';
            echo '<center><b> Update </b></center>';
            echo '</td></tr>';


            while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
            {
                $varRecCount++;
                echo '<tr><td>';
                echo '<center> &nbsp;'.$varRecCount.'</center>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<center> &nbsp;'.odbc_result($rs,"UsrGrpNama").'</center>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<center> &nbsp;'.odbc_result($rs,"MenuNama").'</center>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<center> &nbsp;'.odbc_result($rs,"MenuAkses").'</center>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';                                                                                                                            
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</td></tr>';          
            }

        }
        ?>


</table>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="button" name="btnUpdate" id="btnUpdate" onClick="javascript:sendData('updatedata');" value = "Update">
</div>
```

any help would be much appreciated . TQ

Comment: However you need make unique row using 2 or more column. Otherwise it will update all rows.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the table doesn't have a unique id in the database? Or that it's not being called when fetching the content?

Comment: @Naga ya, I've think of that way to. But I didn't know how do I write of that sql ? `update tblMenuAkses set MenuAkses = 'N' where ???`

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie yes, it doesn't have an unique id for it self. It only contains two foreign key in its table.

Comment: Then whoever designed the database / table should be drawn and quartered. Redesign the table, add an ID column. Idiotic design. Depending on the content, you can do a match for each value / column (unless there are rows that are exactly the same) to get a unique match.

Comment: @NurDiyana `update tblMenuAkses set MenuAkses = 'N' where col_1='some_value1' AND[OR] col_2='some_value2' .... col_n='some_valuen'`;  Operator can be  like or a range or IN. But all together must make some sence.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie ok will try as you suggested cause it doesn't look like there is any other solution can be done. Thanks btw :D

Comment: @Naga that might be work ! Why do I didn't of that way . Ok thank you so much.